# Ajax select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I want to retrive the result of this kind of data list with CakePHP 3

```
<?= $this->Form->select('notif_message', 
    [ 'oui' => 'oui', 'non' => 'non'], array('id' => 'notifmess')); ?>
<?= $this->Form->hidden('notifmessage', ['value' => $notif_message]) ;?>
```

The goal is when a user chosse a value, an Ajax call to this controller be done

```
public function notifmessage() // mise à jour des paramètres de notifications 0  = non, 1 = oui
{

    if ($this->request->is('ajax')) {

    $notifmessage = $this->request->data('notifmessage');

    if($notifmessage == 'oui')
    {
        $new_notif_message = 'non';
    }
    else
    {
         $new_notif_message = 'oui';
    }

    $query = $this->Settings->query()
                        ->update()
                        ->set(['notif_message' => $new_notif_message])
                        ->where(['user_id' => $this->Auth->user('username') ])                            
                        ->execute();

    $this->response->body($new_notif_message);
    return $this->response;

    }
}
```

And i would like to do this call in Ajax without reloading , i have this script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.notif_message').change(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/settings-notif_message',
            data: 'select.notif_message' + val,
            success: function(data) {
                alert('ok');
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert('fail');
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

he doesn't work, nothing happend but i don't know why, i don't have any message in log, i can't debug without indication what doesn't not work

Thanks

Comment: What are the values that are generated for your select element as these are the values that you need to work with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In yout javascript you should use `$('#notifmess').change(…` or `$('[notif_message]').change(…` instead of `$('.notif_message').change(…`.
In CakePHP the first argument of the select method will be used as the name attribute of the select tag.

Update:
In your controller you are retrieving the value of `$_POST['notifmessage']`, which is the name of the hidden input field.
To get the user's choice you either should use `$this->request->data('notif_message');` in the controller, or setting up the ajax request to send the data with `notifmessage` like so:

```
$('[name="notif_message"]').change(function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/settings-notif_message',
        data: {'notifmessage' : this.value},
        success: function(data) {
            // To change selected value to the one got from the server
            $('#notifmess').val(data);

            alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(data) {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
});
```

(Where in this case `this` is referring to <select> tag.)

Comment: great suggestion !, i have the Ajax Call but the rest of my goal doesn't work properly : the update in database are not effective and i want that the 'oui' or 'non' are saved in my view , i didn't found in CakePHP 3 docs how to put a 'selected' y default

Comment: i always have 'oui' , no matter what i choose i always have 'oui', there is something wrong in the controller i guess

Comment: @christ57 I have updated the answer to elaborate on the parameter namings.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works ut how to put the 'selected' to the option choosed in jquery ?

Comment: I have updated the answer once again. Change is: `$('#notifmess').val(data);`, where `data` should be replaced to reflect the data structure coming from your server. (That could be `data.id`, based on your other edits.)

Comment: everything is working, thanks a lot for your help dferenc, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

i'm close to success: my ajax call is working, database update is working , i juste need to put the 'selected' to the other , i'm trying with this jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#notifmess').change(function(){
    var id = $('#notifmess').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/instatux/settings-notif_message',
            data: {'id' : id},
                success: function(data){
     $('#notifmess option[value="'+data.id+'"]').prop('selected', true);

},
error: function(data)
{
    alert('fail');
}

     });
});
```

});